# OpenCV Shape detection ignoring marks along edges using C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

I'm trying to pull out a bounding rect on a page and have to account for the users (small children) who may write on the page messing with outline boxes.

Like this: Top left of the box has writing which interferes with the bounding box contours

[image: 1]

When attempting to get the contours and pull the box it seems the writings that are on the boxes edge cause the contours to no longer have 4 points or may also just extend the box in a direction: Writing on the upper left altered how my box is grabbed

[image: 2]

Below is my code for how I get the contours of the whole page after performing gray, threshold, and Gaussian on the original Image.

```
//Fining the Question circles
Mat copy = guassianBlurImage.Clone();
var circles = Cv2.HoughCircles(copy, HoughModes.Gradient, 1, 10, 1, 25, 13, 14);

//Whitling down the possible selections & Find Bounding Boxes + Biggest Contour Box
OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours = null;
HierarchyIndex[] hierachy = null;

//External because list or tree will also get a inner rectangle for the same box
Cv2.FindContours(thresholdImage, out contours, out hierachy, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxNone);

List<OpenCvSharp.Rect> boundingBoxes = new List<OpenCvSharp.Rect>();
List<OpenCvSharp.Rect> questionBoxes = new List<OpenCvSharp.Rect>();
Dictionary<string, Point2f[]> questionBoxContourDic = new Dictionary<string, Point2f[]>();
   foreach (OpenCvSharp.Point[] c in contours)
   {
       var area = Cv2.ContourArea(c);
       var peri = Cv2.ArcLength(c, true);
       var approx = Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, true);
       OpenCvSharp.Rect r = Cv2.BoundingRect(c);

       //Check if any question bubbles exist in the rect
       bool containsQuestionBubble = false;
       foreach (var cir in circles)
       {
           OpenCvSharp.Point circleCenter = new OpenCvSharp.Point(cir.Center.X, cir.Center.Y);
           if(r.Contains(circleCenter))
           {
               containsQuestionBubble = true;
               break;
           }
       }

       //Ignore words and small boxes
       if (approx.Length == 4 && area > 500)
       {
           Mat temp = new Mat();
           var xCenter = (r.TopLeft.X + r.BottomRight.X) / 2;
           var yCenter = (r.TopLeft.Y + r.BottomRight.Y) / 2;
           Cv2.GetRectSubPix(thresholdImage, new OpenCvSharp.Size(r.Width, r.Height), new Point2f(xCenter, yCenter), temp);

           int total = Cv2.CountNonZero(temp);
           //Adds the Bounding boxes to a list for later
           if (total > 4000 && total < 4700)
           {
               boundingBoxes.Add(r);
           }
           //Adds the questionbox to a list for later
           if (containsQuestionBubble)
           {
               int i = questionBoxContourDic.Count() + 1;
               questionBoxes.Add(r);
               RotatedRect rr = Cv2.MinAreaRect(c);
               Point2f[] corners = Cv2.BoxPoints(rr);
               //Question box name with corner points
               questionBoxContourDic.Add("QuestionBox" + i, corners);
           }
       }
```

If possible I would also like to avoid having the user define areas of interest since this process should remain self sufficient.

Comment: It seems like you are just getting the BB of all the contours. I would probably try to use HoughLines to find the lines for the box.

Comment: With all the words and such on the page Hough lines goes absolutely berserk. I never tried canny edge detection so that's wat I'm trying now. Converting all these numpy functions to c# is a major pain.

Comment: I have not used HoughLines to be honest. But I would expect that you should be able to find the box by adjusting the threshold and filtering the lines to ignore anything not close to horizontal/vertical, not close to image borders, not to close to other lines etc. After all, the [tutorial example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) is not much different from your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating multiple masks for things like bounding boxes, question boxes, etc... and saving them to a json file. The user will have to define these general areas before running the program but since these documents hardly change its not too big of a deal plus they only have to do it once. This allows me to pull up a mask when needed to check if my desired box is within the bounds of the masks white area.